# Order articles in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to order some articles from a category in joomla at this url:

```
http://www.dasphotonics.com/apps/joomla/en/products/electronic-intelligence-and-radar
```

After put the order at the administration panel, optical harmessing I have it on the fourth place but it appears at the 3rd place, why?.

Regards and thank you

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Joomla doesn't order the articles by the backend ordering by default.

There are two ways to change this.

1. Do this ordering Global
2. Set the ordering method in the Menu

The first one could be changed in the Article List->Options (Top Left Button)->Shared Options (Tab)->Article Order (Drop Down) - Change this to Ordering. This will change all Blog and Category views to this type of ordering.

The second option is in the Menuitem. On the right site you have a Slider called "Blog Layout" there is a Option "Article Order" change this to "Article Manager Order". This will change only this Blog or Category view to this type of ordering.

Comment: I did it but nothing. I dit it both. It's fustrating because with others it Works perfectly but with this one, nothing.Why?.

Comment: What type of view is this, is it a blog or a category view? Are the articles in the same category?

Comment: Yes, the articles are in the same category and it's done like a show a category in a blog format.

Comment: Are you really sure that you are editing the correct menu? I tested it and this works fine for me (Joomla 2.5.18). You are using com_k2 is this a default Joomla or K2 content? Would you like to test some order order options?